# Message digest configuration in windows server 2012

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 machine, that is being used an certificate authority (using SCEP).
What is the default message digest algorithm ?
Is it possible to configure it to use a different one ?
I've being looking in documentation, but failed to find any way to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find how to do this.
You need to edit the registry and change the entry under:
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\\CSP\HashAlgorithm
to the algorithms you wish to use.